# Locker Service - something strange happens with attributes after calling component.set()

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I'm working on making my lightning components compliant with Locker Service, and I see something strange happens with javascript variables after calling `component.set()` on them.

A component is having an attribute:

```
<aura:component controller="CPQ_QOT02_ConfigurationLC" access="GLOBAL">
    ...
   <aura:attribute name="item" type="Object" access="GLOBAL"/>
    ...
</aura:component>
```

In the `init` method of controller I'm calling server to fetch `item` variable. Item is a complex JS object having several properties (maps and arrays). Response from server is ok, I'm handling it in `helper` in below lines:

```
line   code

126    if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
127        var item = JSON.parse(response.data);
128        console.log(item);
129        component.set("v.item", item);
130        console.log(component.get("v.item"));
131        ...
```

There is a significant difference between `console.log` that is printed to console in line 128 (before calling set) and in line 130 after calling it.

Here are snapshots from the browser console:

`Console.log` from line 128:

[image: console.log from 128]

`Console.log` from line 130 (after setter was called. Looks like all properties are not directly visible):

[image: console.log from 130]

As a result - whatever I would do later with the `"v.item"` variable - it seems not being applied to that attribute. Before locker service, everything was working fine, but also the result of both console.log's were the same.

Am I doing something wrong, or this is some framework issue?

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue? I activated the locker service today, and ohh boy, some weird stuff are happening! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely supposed to be a "feature" of Locker Service... an object stored in the framework becomes a "SecureObject" instead. Presumably this is designed to enable data binding to the view. But it is not documented particularly well.

Some things I have found:

- Data binding to a JS object works slightly better if you declare the `aura:attribute` as a `Map` not an `Object`.
- When you first `component.set` the Map it should contain all the keys it will ever have, otherwise newly added properties may not bind properly.
- If you pass an object to another component and it tries to modify it and then bind to its own view, you may end up with trouble. Sometimes I find myself cloning objects passed from other components (i.e. using something as silly as `JSON.parse(JSON.serialize(obj))`).

Comment: Thank you for answer @Charles, so as I understand the only option to pass an object to another component and modify it there is this JSON.parse...
If that's the case - I'm in a big trouble.

Comment: I really am not sure how it works, I just know that when a JS object is set from one component and bound to another component which then tries to modify it, there is some trouble. I would like to hear more on this from the SF team.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. If I could give you several upvotes, I would. I've spent the last week or so figuring out these kinds of things - they are not specified anywhere else!!

Comment: A useful detail is that if you want to set the variable's default value to an empty object, you can use `default="{}"` but only if you've set the type to `Map`. If you set type to `Object` it will parse it as a string literal `"{}"`. I should also add, if a variable will contain an array of JS Objects, then you can declare it as type `Map[]` for best results.

Comment: So summarizing, I can see that primitive types seem to be passed properly between parent & child components. Complex types not. 
If I remeber correctly, that's the other way around compared to Visualforce Components.